Send arguments/params to pytest via command without conftest.py
I have a yml template with a job that triggers pytest class.
The file with allt he test classes is (test_invoke_pipelines.py:
import logging
import os

import pytest
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

LOAD_DATA_ENHANCED_PIPELINE = "my-enhanced-pipeline"
PREPROCESS_PIPELINE = "my-preprocess-pipeline"
TRAIN_MONTHLY_PIPELINE = "my-train-pipeline"
SCORE_MONTHLY_PIPELINE = "my-score-pipeline"


class TestDataLoad:
    """Data Load pipeline test cases."""

    @pytest.mark.order(1)
    def test_load_data_pipeline_succeeded(self, adf_pipeline_run):
        """Test that pipeline has data in SQL."""
        this_run = adf_pipeline_run(LOAD_DATA_ENHANCED_PIPELINE, run_inputs={"pl_full_load": True})
        assert this_run.status == "Succeeded"  # noqa: S101

    @pytest.mark.order(2)
    def test_preprocess_pipeline_succeeded(self, adf_pipeline_run):
        """Test that preprocess pipeline works."""
        this_run = adf_pipeline_run(PREPROCESS_PIPELINE, run_inputs={})
        assert this_run.status == "Succeeded"  # noqa: S101


class TestTrainingPipeline:
    """Train pipeline test cases - Used for CT."""

    subscription_id = os.environ.get("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
    resource_group_name = os.environ.get("DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP")
    factory_name = os.environ.get("ADF_NAME")
    pipeline_name = os.environ.get("PIPELINE_NAME")

    print(f"Subscription ID: {subscription_id}")
    print(f"RG Name: {resource_group_name}")
    print(f"Factory Name: {factory_name}")
    print(f"Pipeline Name: {pipeline_name}")

    def test_pipeline_runs(self):
        """Test train pipeline case."""
        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credential, self.subscription_id)

        # Trigger the pipeline run
        pipeline_run = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(self.resource_group_name, self.factory_name, self.pipeline_name)

        # Assert that the pipeline run was successfully initiated
        print(f"Pipeline Run ID: {pipeline_run.run_id}")
        assert pipeline_run.run_id is not None  # noqa: S101

        # Check the pipeline status at the start
        pipeline_status = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(
            self.resource_group_name, self.factory_name, pipeline_run.run_id
        ).status
        assert pipeline_status in ["InProgress", "Queued", "Canceling"]  # noqa: S101
        print(f"##vso[task.setvariable variable=ADF_PIPELINE_RUN_ID]{pipeline_run.run_id}")

for the TestDataLoad, it uses adf test plugin and I call the test using the template (integration-template)below:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: '3 Run Integration Test Data Load'
   inputs:
       azureSubscription: 'datanalytics-${{ parameters.ENV }}'
       scriptType: bash
       scriptLocation: inlineScript
       inlineScript:
           pytest test_invoke_pipelines.py::TestDataLoad --sub_id ${{ parameters.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }} --rg_name ${{ parameters.DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP }} --adf_name ${{ parameters.ADF_NAME }} --sp_tenant_id ${{ parameters.TENANT_ID }} --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-integration-results.xml
       addSpnToEnvironment: true
       workingDirectory: tests

and pytest automatically picks the arguments like subscription_id, resource_group_name when passed with above command as TestDataLoad  uses adf test plugin/extension in pytest.
But for the TestTrainingPipeline, I dnt use the adf plugin and instead use adf sdk to trigger an adf pipeline and write the adf pipeline run id to a variable to it can be used for subsequent steps.
The problem is:
How do I pass the arguments like subscription_id and others to the TestTrainingPipeline class. I have another pipeline that calls this test calss as:
 - task: AzureCLI@2
      name: CTTraining
      displayName: '4 Run Integration Tests Train'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'datanalytics-${{ parameters.ENV }}'
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SUBSCRIPTION_ID]${{ parameters.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP]${{ parameters.DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP }}"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ADF_NAME]${{ parameters.ADF_NAME }}"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PIPELINE_NAME]${{ parameters.TRAIN_PIPELINE_NAME }}"
          
          pytest test_invoke_pipelines.py::TestTrainingPipeline --verbose  --capture=no --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-ct-results.xml
        addSpnToEnvironment: true
        workingDirectory: tests

but it throws the error that arguments are unrecognized.
I do not want to use the conftest.py file. I have also tried writing the parameters to os vars before calling pytest:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SUBSCRIPTION_ID]${{ parameters.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP]${{ parameters.DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP }}"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ADF_NAME]${{ parameters.ADF_NAME }}"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PIPELINE_NAME]${{ parameters.TRAIN_PIPELINE_NAME }}"

but in TestTrainingPipeline class I get None for all these variables:
subscription_id = os.environ.get("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
resource_group_name = os.environ.get("DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP")
factory_name = os.environ.get("ADF_NAME")
pipeline_name = os.environ.get("PIPELINE_NAME", "pl_train_monthly")

Is there a way to pass these arguments from a yml pipeline to the pytestclass?
The trace I get from the failed test is:

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________ TestTrainingPipeline.test_pipeline_runs ____________________
self = <test_invoke_pipelines.TestTrainingPipeline object at
0x7f8b5bd82800>
def test_pipeline_runs(self):
    """Test train pipeline case."""
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()


  adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credential, self.subscription_id)


test_invoke_pipelines.py:55:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ../../../_tool/Python/3.10.12/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/mgmt/datafactory/_data_factory_management_client.py:132:
in init
self._config = DataFactoryManagementClientConfiguration(

self =
<azure.mgmt.datafactory._configuration.DataFactoryManagementClientConfiguration
object at 0x7f8b5bb7e590> credential =
<azure.identity._credentials.default.DefaultAzureCredential object at
0x7f8b5bd83d00> subscription_id = None, kwargs = {}, api_version =
'2018-06-01'
def __init__(self, credential: "TokenCredential", subscription_id: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    api_version: str = kwargs.pop("api_version", "2018-06-01")

    if credential is None:
        raise ValueError("Parameter 'credential' must not be None.")
    if subscription_id is None:


      raise ValueError("Parameter 'subscription_id' must not be None.") E           ValueError: Parameter 'subscription_id' must not


be None.
../../../_tool/Python/3.10.12/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/mgmt/datafactory/_configuration.py:42:
ValueError
-------- generated Nunit xml file: /azp/_work/3/s/tests/test-output.xml --------
------ generated xml file: /azp/_work/3/s/tests/junit/test-ct-results.xml ------
=========================== short test summary info ============================ FAILED test_invoke_pipelines.py::TestTrainingPipeline::test_pipeline_runs -
V...
============================== 1 failed in 0.61s ===============================

It fails becasue the subscription_id is None

Hi @Obiii, is this question related to Azure DevOps or Azure Pipeline? If you are using Azure Pipeline, could you please share your azure pipelines yaml and the debug log of the pipeline? If you are not using Azure DevOps or Azure Pipeline, maybe you need to edit and correct the tag.

Setting up variable sin the bash worked.
SUBSCRIPTION_ID="${{ parameters.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}"
DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP="${{ parameters.DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP }}"
ADF_NAME="${{ parameters.ADF_NAME }}"
PIPELINE_NAME="${{ parameters.TRAIN_PIPELINE_NAME }}"

export SUBSCRIPTION_ID DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP ADF_NAME PIPELINE_NAME

And in the script access as:
subscription_id = os.environ.get("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")
resource_group_name = os.environ.get("DATA_RESOURCE_GROUP")
factory_name = os.environ.get("ADF_NAME")
pipeline_name = os.environ.get("PIPELINE_NAME")


Thanks for sharing the answer! The echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SUBSCRIPTION_ID]${{ parameters.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}" command is used to set a pipeline variable in Azure DevOps, which can be used in subsequent tasks within the same pipeline. However, it does not set an environment variable for the current shell session. Using the export command to set an environment variable for the current session is a good idea!
